# RetrieveRequest ordering

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

while processing the results of the [RetrieveRequest](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/retrieverequest/) fo a data extension, what order can i expect.

it seems to be using the natural order of **_CustomObjectKey**  but is this something that is set in stone, which i can rely on?

Comment: Please add some more info.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't rely on the order of elements returned within a single object. Elements that are arranged as *lists* should be considered order-dependent, such as the first element that appears before the next one is based on ordering, but within a single object, it is a bad idea to assume that the elements will be in any particular order.

Comment: Where you taking this information from?

Comment: @negulvaser The XML and JSON specifications. `{"FirstName":"John","LastName":"Doe"}` is semantically equal to `{"LastName":"Doe","FirstName":"John"}`. This is true *unless* some documentation explicitly states otherwise. Every generic XML and JSON parser in every language I've seen makes those same basic assumptions. No element on the same level as any other element has any higher or preferred priority, unless specifically stated as such by a specific document type. You shouldn't assume any relationship based on order.